# How can I fix configuration errors in ext.net?

Tags: web-config, ext.net

I'm new at ext.net. I create a new project and I change the web.config code but i always take configuration error. What am I supposed to do to fix this? here is my web.config code.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="extnet" type="Ext.Net.GlobalConfig" requirePermission="false"/>
 </configSections>
 <extnet scriptMode="Release"/>
 <!-- See Property Options in README.txt -->
 <!-- 
    The following system.web section is only requited for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
    Information Services 6.0 (or earlier).  This section is not necessary for IIS 7.0 or later.
  -->
 <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="*/ext.axd" verb="*" type="Ext.Net.ResourceHandler" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="DirectRequestModule" type="Ext.Net.DirectRequestModule, Ext.Net"/>
    </httpModules>
    <compilation debug="true">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/></assemblies></compilation></system.web>
<!-- 
    The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet Information Services 7.0.
    It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
-->
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
        <add name="DirectRequestModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="Ext.Net.DirectRequestModule, Ext.Net"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <add name="DirectRequestHandler" verb="*" path="*/ext.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="Ext.Net.ResourceHandler"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sample Web.config for Ext.NET is located in the [Examples Explorer](http://examples.ext.net/#/Getting_Started/Release_Documents/Sample_Web.config/).

Answer (score 0):

Add `</ configuration>` at end of file

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Schema to Visual Studio. I made a schema that you can add manually.

http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?27683-XML-Extnet-Schema-to-avoid-Information-Error-in-web-config

Add this code before  tag into DotNetConfig.xsd schema.
I create the element based on 2.4.0 README File. http://examples.ext.net/#/Getting_St...uments/README/

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
  <xs:element name="extnet" vs:help="configuration/extnet">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="ajaxViewStateMode" use="optional">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Default" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Exclude" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Include" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
      <xs:attribute name="cleanResourceUrl" type="small_boolean_Type" use="optional" />
      <xs:attribute name="dateTimeZoneHandling" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
      <xs:attribute name="disableViewState" type="small_boolean_Type" use="optional" />
      <xs:attribute name="directEventUrl" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
      <xs:attribute name="directMethodProxy" use="optional">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Default" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Include" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Ignore" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
      <xs:attribute name="directMethodNamespace" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
      <xs:attribute name="glyphFontFamily" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
      <xs:attribute name="gzip" type="small_boolean_Type" use="optional" />
      <xs:attribute name="idMode" use="optional">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Client" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Explicit" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Ignore" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Inherit" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Legacy" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Parent" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Predictable" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Static" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
      <xs:attribute name="initScriptMode" use="optional">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Inline" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Linked" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
      <xs:attribute name="licenseKey" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
      <xs:attribute name="locale" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
      <xs:attribute name="namespace" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
      <xs:attribute name="renderScripts" use="optional">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Embedded" />
            <xs:enumeration value="File" />
            <xs:enumeration value="CDN" />
            <xs:enumeration value="None" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
      <xs:attribute name="renderStyles" use="optional">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Embedded" />
            <xs:enumeration value="File" />
            <xs:enumeration value="CDN" />
            <xs:enumeration value="None" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
      <xs:attribute name="resourcePath" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
      <xs:attribute name="resourcesStrategyType" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
      <xs:attribute name="resetStyles" type="small_boolean_Type" use="optional" />
      <xs:attribute name="rethrowAjaxExceptions" type="small_boolean_Type" use="optional" />
      <xs:attribute name="rtl" type="small_boolean_Type" use="optional" />
      <xs:attribute name="scriptMode" use="optional">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Release" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Debug" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Development" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
      <xs:attribute name="showWarningOnAjaxFailure" type="small_boolean_Type" use="optional" />
      <xs:attribute name="sourceFormatting" type="small_boolean_Type" use="optional" />
      <xs:attribute name="stateProvider" use="optional">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="PostBack" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Cookie" />
            <xs:enumeration value="None" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
      <xs:attribute name="submitDisabled" type="small_boolean_Type" use="optional" />
      <xs:attribute name="theme" use="optional">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Default" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Access" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Gray" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Neptune" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
      <xs:attribute name="themePath" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
      <xs:attribute name="quickTips" type="small_boolean_Type" use="optional" />
      <xs:anyAttribute namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" processContents="strict"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Then you can debug what is wrong on your ext.net configuration. And additionally you can use and have Ext.net Intellisense on web.config :D